# Is there a surefire way to validate the existence of a URL?

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, url, ping

I have a C# MVC4 website, call it foo.org.  In it there are "pages" such as foo.org/news or foo.org/events.  This is an http website, not https.

I have another C# MVC4 website, also an http site, that administers the first one (on the same webserver).  In the latter website I need to validate the existence of pages such as "foo.org/news" in the first one.

Both are intranet sites.

foo.org/news and foo.org/events are actually valid pages.  If I were to slap their urls on the address bar of a browser, they appear,... no problem.

I tried several suggestion from SO and other forums as well to no avail.

Things I tried:

```
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(uri) as HttpWebRequest;
request.Method = "HEAD";
HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse);
var retval = (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK);
response.Close();
return retval;
```

and

```
var pingSender = new Ping();
var options = new PingOptions();
options.DontFragment = true;
var data = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
var buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
var timeout = 120;
var reply = pingSender.Send(uri, timeout, buffer, options);
return (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success);
```

and

```
IPHostEntry ipHost = Dns.GetHostEntry(safeHost);
return (ipHost.HostName != null && ipHost.HostName != "");
```

In each, I tried with and without prepending "http://".

Now I combine all 3 by trying one after the other and return the first success I encounter.  I can validate urls such as google.com or foo.org but not when I have "/news" appended to foo.org.

The above code is not exactly as I have it, just the meat of it.

Comment: Only your first option can actually check for a webpage.  What does it return when you try it?  Does it work if you change the method to "Get"?

Comment: My goodness...GET worked!  Such a simple solution.  I still need to leave the other methods there as well as a version of the first one that uses HEAD to validate other URLs.  But thanks again.  Perhaps you can put an actual response post so I can flag it and credit you with an "answer".

Comment: Just a note, you are not actually verifying the existance of the web page, just it's current availability. If the server is down for a bit, it doesn't mean the page doesn't exist (there is no way to verify existance) just that it is unavailable. When the server comes back up it will be available again.

Comment: I get your point.  Although I might debate that the unavailability of a web-page can mean the non-existence of it, at least for the duration of the test.  But I agree, I should have phrased the question with "to test the availability of a URL".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorting your options by how well they will validate the URL from worst to best:

- Your 3rd option only looks up a DNS record for the URL.  It will return true even if there isn't a web server listening for that IP.
- The 2nd option will ping the web server, but you aren't guaranteed that pings are allowed (which would give a false negative) or that the device responding is the actual webserver (which would give a false positive).
- The 1st option will talk to the webserver to verify the page, but not all servers will respond correctly to a `HEAD` request (which is probably your problem in this case).  This will still have false positives and false negatives, but it is better than the above options.
- A variant of the 1st option is to change the HTTP method to a `GET` request instead.  This will ask the webserver for the actual webpage.  This will give the most correct answer to see if the webpage exists, but there will always be some cases where you will not get the correct answer.